# How to control field properties when importing csv to Arc gdb

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, file-geodatabase, csv

I am writing Python code to import csv files with UK postcodes to ArcGIS file gdb.
The import works fine, however, text fields in newly created table in gdb have length of 8000 characters.

Is there a way to control field properties in a table before importing from csv?

Comment: Would it be possible to see some of the code you have writte to get a sense of the workflow you have developed so far?

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible to do it directly. 
A workaround is to create a feature class in the gdb with the correct settings for the text fields. Import the csv data afterwards.

1. `right click` the newly created feature class
2. choose `load > load data`
3. follow the wizard
4. done!